# Tengo este metodo que es para la autentificacion de usuario y no se porque no me funciona

Tags: php, api, webservice, login

A continuacion tengo el siguiente codigo para el login de usuario:

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';

    $pdo = new Conexion();


    //Login usuario
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if(!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
            
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT usuarioid, usuario, password 
            FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password =:pasword");

            $sql->bindValue(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
            $sql->bindValue(':password', $_POST['password']);
            $sql->execute(); //se ejecuta
            $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //datos del usuario
            
            header("HTTP/1.1 201 Login correcto");
            echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll()); //imprime todas las reservas de esa fecha
            exit;
        }
        else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 error con el login");
            
        }
    }
?>
```

Pero al comprobarlo por postman no me funciona, se va directamente al ultimo else y no se porque. No que es lo que esta fallando.

Esto es lo que pongo en postman:
localhost/login/login.php?usuario=sara@gmail.com&password=sara123
o en formato json:

```
{"usuario":"sara@gmail.com",
"password":"sara123"}

Y ahora lo he vuelto a ejecutar y me sale este error que antes no me salúa. ¿Alguna idea?

>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php:19

Me sale que es la linea 19, pero en la lunea 19 tengo el execute()
```

Comment: Tienes seleccionado en postman, en la pestaña de body los campos usuario y password definidos? Pon una captura de pantalla del postman, a ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: @Aitana Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que envías con postman ?

Comment: Hola, un ejemplo de postman seria el siguiente: localhost/login/login.php?usuario=sara@gmail.com&password=sara123.

Comment: eso esta mal planteado en postman lo que envias por la URL se considera un GET y tu lo quieres recibir por POST ...

Comment: y esto tambien esta mal:  `usuario = :usuario` debe ser  `usuario=:usuario` pegado el igual con los dos puntos...